# DOCTYPE and HEAD loading incorrectly in PHP

Tags: php

Below is the my index page.  $page is defined at the top, and then the sections of the page (header, menu, body & footer) are changed out at the bottom.

The problem I'm running into is that the DOCTYPE and  data are not loading first, before the remaining page content.  This causes the browser to run in quirks mode.

Let me know if/how I can make this question clearer.

Thanks in advance for your time!

UPDATE:
I have removed all PHP tags, and set the require('includes/....') to variables to eliminate on page load.  The DOCTYPE still refuses to load.  Code below reflects the changes.

UPDATE 2:
DOCTYPE is now directly butted up to the $page variable, eliminating all whitespace.  Also, when viewing in the browser, I noticed that  is shown, even though the opening  is not.  All stylesheets and other  content is rendered inside the  of the page.

SOLUTION:
The solution could have been multiple factors, as pointed out by multiple people (Such as newlines being generated before the DOCTYPE), but I can only say for sure that the final answer was as follows:
The external documents being called into the $page were not set to variables.  Thus, they seemed to be loading before the page.  Once I set the external includes/requires to variables in their respect documents, the DOCTYPE loaded properly.  I can't thank you all enough for your time.

```
<?
require('includes/functions/get_content.php');
$header=require('includes/header.php');
$footer=require('includes/footer.php');

$page='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Website Name</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/primary_layout.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bodyContainer">                
%HEADERS%

%MENU%

<div id="bodyContentPane" role="main">
%BODY%
</div> <!-- Close bodyContentPane -->
%FOOTER%
</div>
</body>
</html>';

//############### LOAD BODY CONTENT and SET CATEGORY ###############
$p = $_GET['p'];
switch ($p){ 
case "port-a-cool":
$filename='includes/content1.html';
$data=get_content($filename);
$product_category = '1';
$body=$data;
break;

case "radiant-heaters":
$filename='includes/content2.html';
$data=get_content($filename); 
$product_category = '2';
$body=$data;
break;

default:
$body= include('includes/index.php');
break;
}

//############### DEFINE CONTENT TO LOAD BY CATEGORY ###############
$i = $product_category;
switch ($i){
case "1":
$menu=include('includes/menus/content1.php');
break;
case "2":
$menu=include('includes/menus/content2.php');
break;  }

// ############### CHECK FOR UNDEFINED SUB MENU ###############
if ($menu=="")
$menu = include ('includes/menus/default.php');

$page=str_replace('%HEADER%',$header,$page); 
$page=str_replace('%MENU%',$menu,$page); 
$page=str_replace('%BODY%',$body,$page);
$page=str_replace('%FOOTER%',$footer,$page); 
echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: Does get_content.php, header.php or footer.php render any content? In that case you will have to render our doctype and head before you require() or include() those files.

Comment: Why do you have a `$page` variable???

Comment: You have countless `?>

<?` spitting out white spaces before you output any html.

Comment: @Maritim - Man, I don't know what I was thinking.  I think you're right.  Been staring at this way too long...get_content is only a function, but header.php and footer.php do have content.  Will try that now.

Comment: @relentless - The $page allows me to style the page on a global level, and pull content into it through the str_replace at the bottom.

Comment: @Musa - May I ask what you mean by spitting out white space?  Does closing and opening php tags generate white space?

Comment: @RAB it doesn't generate white space that is parsed by the browser as html whitespace

Comment: Generally speaking you don't want anything before doctype. Not even simple newlines. A lot of browsers might handle it but until you've declared the doctype you haven't really set the rules for how stuff is supposed to get parsed so it could easily be quirksmode for you.

Comment: @ErikReppen - That's an excellent thing to know.  Especially since I only noticed the problem after a long way into the project, when testing it on an older IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have white spaces before your doctype, here

```
$page='
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

remove the spaces

```
$page='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Note: For `$header=require('includes/header.php');` to return content you'll have to have something like `return 'the content';` in the included file.

Comment: @RAB Maybe you should post you included files so we can see if they output anything.

Comment: Well, I've now set them to variables so they don't even load until called.  Take a look at the revised question and let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @RAB for `$header=require('includes/header.php');` to return content  you'll have to have something like `return 'the content';` in the included file.

Comment: I think I understand.  I need to return a variable as the output in the external file?  After yanking parts of the code out, chunk by chunk, I seem to have it narrowed down to what you just mentioned.  Will try it now...

Comment: Well, that ended up being the problem.  If you are able to update your answer, with the section about returning the external documents, I'll pick it as the answer for future people.  And Thank You(!) very much.  I have other problems, but at least this very large one is behind me.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably happening because you have a lot of whitespace being output in front of the page content.

If you view the source of the page you should see several empty lines output prior to the doctype.

The newlines are getting output before the page content because of the newlines between your PHP tags.

For example:

```
<?
require('includes/functions/get_content.php');
require('includes/header.php');
require('includes/footer.php');
?>

<?
page='
```

Outputs one newline before the PHP tag where you set the `$page` variable.

The solution will be to eliminate all newlines between your php tags, so either don't switch between PHP tags when there is no need, or make sure there isn't an empty line between the opening and closing tags.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think that would cause the doctype to not get set. Newlines are not parsed as html

Comment: @drew010 - Ohh, that's what Musa meant above ^^.  Opening and closing the PHP tags doesn't generate the whitespace, it's the HTML being generated between them.  Man, now that you point it out, I feel a bit silly doing it this way.  I was trying to keep my code clean and easy to review!

I would upvote your answer, but can't yet.  Thank you though!

Comment: @Shredder In some browsers (particularly IE), any output before the doctype including whitespace will trigger quirks mode so the doctype has to be at the very beginning of the document.

Comment: @drew010 - Based on the revised code in the question, do you happen to see anything else?  Sorry to bother you, but I've run out of ideas on what could be causing the problem.

Comment: It's looking better now, but if you view the source of the page is there anything still preceding the doctype or anything else strange about the output?

Comment: @drew010 - Well, sorry about the delay.  Was pursuing a different rabbit trail that seemed to solve the problem.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that none of the files that you are requiring or including are not outputting anything to the browser. If they are, they will be outputted before the doctype gets declared and it will be forced to enter quirks mode.

Comment: Absolutely.  That was a clumsy mistake on my part.  The requires have now been changed to variables.  The problem still persists though.

Comment: Do me a favor. Comment out `/* */` everything except your `$page` declaration and when you `echo $page;` and tell me if it is still quirks mode :)

Comment: I should have done that from the beginning.  The problem persists.

Comment: BUT, if I then removed the variables/includes, the DOCTYPE works!  How is that possible, since it's set as a variable?

Comment: The variables/includes were part of the 'everything' :P include statements work like require. Any file that is included will get parsed as part of the script. Make sure nothing there is being outputted to the browser. You can keep doing this process of commenting/elimination until you find your culprit :)